# How to compute a function on a group (as aggregation)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas-groupby, alteryx

I took a simple example with this table.

I want to compute a column which group by "Fact":

- and return `France` if all the country in Country1 and Country2 for the same "Fact" number are all "France"
- and return any country (the most frequent) if it exists for a given "Fact" number an other country than France.

How would you achieve that ?

I am trying to achieve it with Alteryx (which operate approximately like SQL since we perform Join, Aggregation, Filter, etc...) and can't imagine an easy process.

How would you solve that problem with alteryx,SQL, or Python [Edit: i would be really interested by the way you would solve it with the library pandas (in Python) also. I think that it is possible after grouping/agregating, to apply custom function on each group (which is similar to an indexed dataframe) and the process would be easier)]?

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Edit: yes as suggested 3 should be France and 4: Spain !

Comment: 3 should be France not spain

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the second part of the logic `and return any country` because don't see how Fact 3 return Spain or why Fact 4 doesnt show.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: What version of MySQL can handle alteryx? Can you use `WITH` or `ROW_NUMBER()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need combine both country fields in a single field, we call this `t`

```
SELECT Fact, Country1 as Country
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Fact, Country2
FROM Table1
```

Now using conditional aggregation found how many `France` has each `Fact`

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN Country = 'France' THEN 1 END) as total_france,
COUNT(Country) as total_country
```

**Partial Result** we call this `r`

```
| Fact | total_france | total_country |
|------|--------------|---------------|
|    1 |            3 |             4 |
|    2 |            1 |             2 |
|    3 |            4 |             4 |
|    4 |            1 |             4 |
```

Finally if `total_france = total_country` we return `France` otherwise we look for the most frequent Country other than France in that Fact group.

Notice in case of Ties in frequency I return any of the country. You could modify to additional sort by Name for example.

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/829d18/10)**

```
SELECT Fact, CASE WHEN total_france = total_country 
                  THEN 'France' 
                  ELSE (SELECT Country
                        FROM   (SELECT Fact, Country1 as Country
                                FROM Table1
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT Fact, Country2
                                FROM Table1
                                ) s
                        WHERE r.Fact = s.Fact
                          AND s.Country <> 'France'
                        GROUP BY Country
                        ORDER BY Count(*) DESC
                        LIMIT 1)                        
             END as Country
FROM (
      SELECT Fact, 
             COUNT(CASE WHEN Country = 'France' THEN 1 END) as total_france,
             COUNT(Country) as total_country
      FROM (
            SELECT Fact, Country1 as Country
            FROM Table1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT Fact, Country2
            FROM Table1
           ) t
      GROUP BY Fact
     ) r;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| Fact | Country |
|------|---------|
|    1 | England |
|    2 | Germany |
|    3 |  France |
|    4 |   Spain |
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are after the results to be

```
|Fact   |Country|
|1      |England|
|2      |Germany|
|3      |France |
|4      |Spain  |
```

then in Alteryx the order of tools will be:

- Transpose
- 2 Parallel Summarizes (one group by Fact & Name, the other by Fact)
- Join (on Fact)
- Filter (Count = Right Count): To move aside any where every value is the same
- Filter off False (Value = France)
- Sort off False: Count Descending
- Unique: on Fact
- Union: Unique with the True from the first filter
- Select & Sort: To tidy up

Essentially, what you are doing is splitting out the Constant values before finding the most common "non-France" values and unioning the whole lot back together.